# Undefined symbols on Mac M1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I recently bought a Mac with a Silicon processor (M2 Pro) and since then my iOS application does not build anymore.

I have a framework that I had to install by hand and I have the following errors:

[image: errors]

I checked that the framework was in `Embed & Sign` mode in `General > Frameworks, Librairies, and Embedded Content` and that it was well linked in `Build Phases > Link Binaiy With Libraries`.
I also checked that the framework had the right Target Mebership.

Everything works fine on my old Intel mac, and I can't seem to find the solution, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this for the iOS target or the Simulator target?

Comment: For the simulator

Comment: did you open xcode with rosetta?

Comment: Then the most likely cause is that your framework contains an arm64 slice for iOS and an x86_64 slice for the Simulator, but no arm64 one for the Simulator. And if it's a regular framework with a fat Mach-O inside, then it can't actually contain more than one binary per architecture. I believe the XCFramework format was made to work around this issue, but I never dealt with that.

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar No, I open xcode normally

Comment: @Siguza So it means that I have no way to build the application on the simulator until the framework is updated?

Comment: @R3J3CT3D not the arm64 simulator anyway. You may still be able to build for and run in the x86_64 simulator. But yes, the framework needs to be updated by its vendor. You could try and take the iOS binary and patch some load command in the Mach-O header to change its platform to simulator, but I don't know how well that would work.